# Does the font matter when putting a manuscript on arXiv?

Tags: publications, formatting, preprint

I have a research paper that I want to upload on arXiv. Almost all the papers I have seen on arXiv are written in *Times New Roman*. I understand scientific papers are written in that font mostly. But I have seen papers from DeepMind and other AI labs writing in a wide variety of fonts including *Trebuchet MS*.

I've written my paper in *Trebuchet MS* because it is an easily readable font. Do I need to change my font into *Times New Roman* or will *Trebuchet MS* be fine with arXiv? I was unable to find a clear answer onlibe or in the submission guidelines.

Comment: Is "arvix" a typo for "Arxiv"? Or some other website?

Comment: It sounds like your have written your paper in MS Word. Assuming you mean arXiv instead of "Arvix", they mostly accept papers written in LaTeX and as such the typeface won't be Times New Roman or anything like that, but typically Computer Modern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand Scientific papers are written in Times New Roman font mostly

Regarding this premise, it is probably not correct for arXiv papers. As you may know, arXiv covers a range of topics but mainly invites papers on mathematics, physics, computer science and related areas. These papers are written mainly in LaTeX. The default font in LaTeX is Computer Modern.

> I've written my paper in "Trebuchet MS" because it is an easily readable font.

Many modern fonts are "better" than Computer Modern in one way or another. However, note that Trebuchet MS is designed primarily as a web font that should render well in browsers. Research papers typically are distributed in pdf, and benefit most from fonts that are designed for printing on paper. A web font may be nice and readable on screen but appear poorly on paper when printed.

During arXiv submission you will have an opportunity to check the final pdf as it will appear for readers. You may simply submit paper to arXiv and see if you encounter any issues during the submission. In case of any problems it's best to approach the arXiv support team for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble with a specific product (i.e. arXiv), you should write first to the product maintainers (i.e. [Contact section](https://arxiv.org/help/contact)).

How are you producing your document? you can submit to arXiv only in 3 family of formats (in order of preference):

1. (La)TeX, AMS(La)TeX, PDFLaTeX
2. PDF
3. HTML with JPEG/PNG/GIF images

Regarding pdf, [they clearly state](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_pdf):

> You must ensure that all non-standard fonts are included and that
> outline (TrueType/Type1) rather than bitmap (Type3) fonts are used. In
> Adobe Distiller and many other products this is referred to as
> compatibility mode and will ensure that the PDF document is as
> portable as possible.

So it boils down to:

- do you have the rights to share a document with Trebuchet? do you need permission from the copyrights'owners?
- can you technically bring the font in your LaTex or PDF or HTML document?

Good luck finding [someone to endorse you](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) (since you state you are a high-school student...) and good luck with your research work!

Comment: This font seems unencumbered by any restrictions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet_MS

Comment: I've worked with MIT, Stanford and Oxford University professors. I believe I can ask them for endorsing me :) Though this research paper is my own work. Btw Thank you for answering and your best wishes!

Comment: @Buffy I am sure the answer cannot be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/fonts/font-faq but I am sure that page must be read to ask the proper question to arXiv people